# Can Ubuntu ignore the Wireless Hardware Switch?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, rfkill

This is not the same question as many others have asked. I have a perfectly functioning wireless card and switch on my HP Pavilion dv6910, running Ubuntu 12.04.

Unfortunately, the placement of this switch causes me to hit it when the notebook is sitting on my lap.

I'm looking to disable the switch's functionality to prevent disabling the wireless. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a _button_ or a _switch_?  Most HP laptops have buttons, most Dells switchs.

Comment: It is indeed an on/off switch, not a button.

Comment: Can you add the output of `xmodmap -pke` please?

Comment: `xmodmap -pke` output: [http://pastebin.com/rXy4LCdi](http://pastebin.com/rXy4LCdi)

Comment: Can you try running `xmodmap -e clear XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN`?  This is really, really, far fetched but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

Check your BIOS. HP has some HP-only features in the BIOS.  In the `Built-In Device Configuration` menu there should be an option `LAN/WLAN-Switching`.  You should be able to disable it there.  (it has been a while since I had a HP so if this is not correct please comment ;) )

Comment: Not sure about this one, but I'll check and get back to you. If at all possible, I'm wondering if this can be done in software, so I can easily remove the "block" without rebooting.

Comment: Nope those kill switches are hardware linked and the OS has no control over it. You can turn in on or off but not disabled it (so you would still turn it of when hitting it accidently).